# Is there an inward (radial) force acting on a magnet inside a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

With a magnet inside another hollow magnet, for example an iron rod in a hollow cylinder, the iron bar placed inside the cylinder with poles attracted to opposite poles of cylinder (likes repel opposites attract), is there also a force along the radius of the cylinder? Per the closed loop rule, the magnetic flux along the sides of the iron rod flows in opposite direction to that of the cylinder. It would seem like the magnetic flux on the inside of the cylinder "squeezes" its way past opposite flux from the iron rod (the iron rod being fixed in place along the longitudinal axis by attraction at poles), compressing it from all directions at once, repelling the iron rod with a vector towards the centre of the radial axis.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/28354/10902

Comment: What have you done towards a solution? Measurements? Field strength?

Comment: re: duplicate, this question is more generic, often easier the more well defined the question

Comment: The subject is not my expertise, I specialize in other fields, and so I use a collaborative Q&A.

Comment: People on here offer help when effort is shown - we are not a free homework completion service...

Comment: The idea is based on, simply, that the magnetic flux of the inner magnet flows (seems to me) in opposite direction to magnetic flux of outer magnet. That suggests there would be a force between the two, in general.

Comment: Stackexchange is a free Q&A though, although yes sure not homework employees. If there was an incentivized alternative that accepted payments, I would probably use it since it would be more productive and provide better service.

Comment: We are not paid to solve your problems, most are here out of interest. You are **most** welcome to go elsewhere...

Comment: Yes I am aware that this is not a payed service. What I said was that if there was an incentivized platform, I would probably use it because it would be superior. That was not meant as an insult, it was another way to say that I am not looking for homework completion :)

Comment: actually. it is more that I want to have my assumptions validated, rather than having homework done. I have done the work, as in, I am interested in whether the assumption is correct (do you see difference?).

Comment: so best analogy would be grading homework, but I think "homework" metaphor overall is a bit statist.

Comment: this question can for example be reduced to two bar magnets, side by side, with opposite polarity. https://i.imgur.com/CjiiPNF.png. do they experience a repulsive force at null point? (that is my assumption)

Comment: In other words, the intent is to get certainty, by having experts give their opinion which tends to be accurate. That may not be appreciated, but it is very different from looking for homework completion service :)

Comment: You will find that some things do not improve with exchange of money. In fact the quid for pro social economy is multiple times more efficient than markets.

Comment: As much as that comment sounds nice, it is not really true. Legal systems, coordination mechanisms, and incentives, including reward incentives, as well as money etc, _have_ improved pro-social coordination. The reason incentivized wikipedia and/or incentivized stackexchange doesn't exist is just because the technology it requires is still in its infancy, Ethereum was a good start.